# Function for tag_bind runs when defining it

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, mouseevent

I'm pretty new to python and programming in general but I just managed to create a tree view using a, what I think, ambitious for-loop. The idea is that each item in the list represents a class carrying a method which should be generated when clicking the item. The thing is now that this function tends to run when creating the tree, but when clicking the item nothing happens.

Code:

```
for i in range(0,len(iclass.OPS)):

    jclass = iclass.OPS[i]
    childID = "%s-%s" % (parentID, child_count)
    self.tree.insert(parentID, 'end', childID, text = jclass.treeID)
    self.tree.tag_bind(childID, '<Double-1>', jclass.tree_func() )
    self.populate_tree(childID, jclass)
    child_count += 1
```

The tree_func in question is the defined within the actual class as:

```
def tree_func(self, event):
    print "hi!"
```

for example...
Can't see what the problem is. I've done similar stuff with list boxes and that worked.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: use function name - without `()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the callable itself, not the result of calling it.

```
self.tree.tag_bind(childID, '<Double-1>', jclass.tree_func)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually got it running at last but it wasn't just because of the () it didn't work. Forgot to mention that I tried both. What made the trick was that I gave the tag to my tree object by writing:

```
self.tree.insert(parentID, 'end', tags = childID, text = jclass.treeID)
```

instead of just

```
self.tree.insert(parentID, 'end', childID, text = jclass.treeID)
```